# How can I increase the execution time of aws lambda function more than 5 min?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have lambda function that take more than 5 min to run. How can I increase the execution time of lambda function more than 5 min so my program can keep going?

END RequestId: 5b676871-1eef-1xex-bxxa-47xxxxad8d63

The last line show this in cloudwatch. It automatically end the request.

Comment: And what lambda function are you talking about? Could you please post your code?

Comment: 5min is the maximum execution time.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your use-case? For example: Why do you want it to be longer than 5 minutes? If your code requires longer time, why have you chosen to run it as a Lambda function? What is the task doing -- can it be broken into multiple separate tasks that could be run in parallel?

Answer (score 55):

You cannot increase the runtime to more than 15 minutes.

The [AWS Lambda `limit` page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) states the `Function timeout` is `900 seconds (15 minutes)`. If you need more than 15 minutes of execution time you have to look at other services. You could have a look if [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) would suit your needs.

**Updated:** The limit was changed from 5 minutes to 15 minutes.

Comment: Agreed, + step functions

Comment: This is quite disappointing! I don't see any benefit to restricting us to 5 minutes. Does anyone know why this constraint exists?

Comment: Would also like to know? Every time you need run jobs with an undefined scope / length you run the risk of dropping the job halfway through, which is mostly a dealbreaker.. Spinning up a batch job easily takes 1 to 5 minutes to fire, also not ideal.. Breaking the job up in micro jobs over Lambda makes keeping log of job status / success more complicated. Feels like the 5 minute limit is really blocking a lot of use cases, intentionally.

Comment: Seems like it got increased to 15 minutes
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: @LVBen, keep in mind that the lambda runs on any available machine.  AWS wouldn't want lambdas to get in the way of restarting a machine.  That's probably a reason that lambdas have limited lifetimes.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can. My solution is:

1. Track time elapse in your lambda function
2. When it about to exceeds the limit, send a notification to SNS topic, then exit.
3. Set the SNS topic as trigger to your lambda function.

Keep in mind lambda's original purpose is to run short task so it's better to keep your lambda function run within 15 mins.

Answer (score 4):

Now you can run AWS Lambda up to 15 minutes!

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  If you need longer time then you need to spin-up an EC2 server instead.

Comment: Is EC2 really the general best practice suggested replacement for lambda when running a script that runs longer than 15 minutes? What about putting the script in a container and spinning that up with fargate?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Timeout` properties of AWS lambda function up to maximum 15 minute.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html